# The junk would then burn up before it strikes the ground VS before it struck the ground?

Tags: grammar

The junk would then burn up before it strikes the ground vs 
The junk would then burn up before it struck the ground?

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, if that's what you're asking. But neither makes sense, since if the junk has burnt up first, how can it then hit the ground? Perhaps you mean "the junk would burn up before it *could strike* the ground"?

Comment: @Chappo No, that usage is fine (although many of us would indeed prefer your phrasing). For example, the OED has this sample sentence in its entry for *before*: *The record company went broke **before** any of their records were issued.* Yes, you can say *before any of their records **could** be issued,* but you don't need to.

Comment: @linguisticturn horses for courses. The OED example sounds ok (just), but the OP's example doesn't, to me at least. A key aspect of language is to communicate the message rather than causing (at least some of) the audience to pause and consider the words used.

Comment: @Chappo Consider the following examples from published literature: *Most of them burn up before they reach the ground.* [(five sources)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Most+of+them+burn+up+before+they+reach+the+ground%22) *Substances capable of melting into glass would, of course, burn up before they hit the surface of the earth.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=EIWWpUOtdgUC&lpg=PA35&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

Comment: @Chappo *Most of them burn up before hitting the ground, and those that survive the fall are usually rather small.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=GywdAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA14&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

*Meteors burn up before they reach Earth, so they do not hit anything on the surface.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=XCb0W8fAzY8C&lpg=PA230&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

Comment: @Chappo *Many are so small that they burn up before making it all the way down to the surface!* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Fu8BgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA24&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

*Particles smaller than optimum could travel farther, but would burn up before landing.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ASSwbHXt4asC&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

Comment: @Chappo We should decide what the question is. The options are these: 1. Are the original sentences (OSs) *linguistically acceptable* in their intended meaning? 2. Are the OSs written as well and as effectively as they can be? If the question is 2., then I agree with you: the fact that a portion of the audience will find the OSs difficult to parse, but will have no such problem if *could* is added to them, means that to maximize the effectiveness one should add *could*. But if the question is 1., then the examples from the published literature show that the OSs are acceptable as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these are linguistically acceptable and mean the same thing:

[1]  a.  *The junk would then burn up before it strikes the ground.*
       b.  *The junk would then burn up before it struck the ground.*
       c.  *The junk would then burn up before striking the ground.*
       d.  *The junk would then burn up before it could strike the ground.*

Instead of *could* one can use some equivalent expression, such as

*The junk would then burn up before it **had a chance to** strike the ground.*

One may also add the word *even*, either in front of *before*, or like this:

*The junk would then burn up before it **even** strikes the ground.

The junk would then burn up before it **even** struck the ground.

The junk would then burn up before **even** striking the ground.

The junk would then burn up before it could **even** strike the ground.*

However, I agree with Chappo that as far as the quality and effectiveness of writing, [1d] is the best option. The reason is that some speakers, upon first reading, take the clauses after *before* in [1a-c] to imply that the striking of the ground actually happened, which leaves them wondering how that could be possible given that the object had burned up. True, these readers will very soon realize what the intended meaning was. Nevertheless, any difficulty in parsing interrupts the flow of reading, which is undesirable, and should be avoided if possible. And here it is indeed possible: the phrasing in [1d] does not have this difficulty. Also, to a large extent, adding *even* ameliorates this problem.

Here are some examples from published literature:

[1a]:

*Most of them burn up before they **reach** the ground.* [(five sources)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22Most+of+them+burn+up+before+they+reach+the+ground%22)

*Meteors burn up before they **reach** Earth, so they do not hit anything on the surface.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=XCb0W8fAzY8C&lpg=PA230&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA230#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

[1b]:

*Others may disappear before we **knew** they existed.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Others+may+disappear+before+we+knew+they+existed%22)

*Henrietta could not abide her son-in-law and hoped that he would simply disappear before the child **was** irreparably injured.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=gu78JKzMB2cC&lpg=RA1-PA1&dq=%22Henrietta%20could%20not%20abide%20her%20son-in-law%20and%20hoped%20that%20he%20would%20simply%20disappear%20before%20the%20child%20was%20irreparably%20injured.%22&pg=RA1-PA1#v=onepage&q=%22Henrietta%20could%20not%20abide%20her%20son-in-law%20and%20hoped%20that%20he%20would%20simply%20disappear%20before%20the%20child%20was%20irreparably%20injured.%22&f=false)

[1c]:

*Most of them burn up before **hitting** the ground, and those that survive the fall are usually rather small.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=GywdAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA14&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

*Many are so small that they burn up before **making** it all the way down to the surface!* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Fu8BgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA24&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

*Particles smaller than optimum could travel farther, but would burn up before **landing**.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ASSwbHXt4asC&dq=%22burn%20up%20before%22&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=%22burn%20up%20before%22&f=false)

[1d]:

*Her dream would disappear before it **could** reach the conclusion that she so longed for.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=nb_bW7iODITj_AbX4YKYCQ&q=%22her+dream+would+disappear+before+it+could+reach+the+conclusion+that+she+so+longed+for%22&oq=%22her+dream+would+disappear+before+it+could+reach+the+conclusion+that+she+so+longed+for%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...75092.75092.0.75637.1.1.0.0.0.0.68.68.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.kkUea0VwcyA)

*A tear glistened at the corner of her eye, but she dabbed at it before it **could** fall.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=hxhTQRFkVlkC&lpg=PT31&dq=%22before%20it%20could%22&pg=PT31#v=onepage&q=%22before%20it%20could%22&f=false)

Comment: +1 I think this addresses both perspectives - grammar, and effective communication :-)